# C Linked List infinite loop

Tags: c, linked-list, embedded

I am trying to edit part of a backnet stack to not use malloc as it always fails. The code uses malloc to create an object and insert into a linked list. In the following code snippet I have commented out the malloc. My plan is to create a local instance of the struct and insert that into my list. I am able to insert 2 items into my list, when trying to add the third, the list is not properly terminated and I enter an infinite while loop. Can anyone see why my list is not properly terminated?

CHobjects is a stuct and I want a linked list of them. I can not use malloc to create new CHobject instances. To get around this I am attempting to create a local instance of CHobject and add that to my list.

```
CHobjects* newNode(instance, channel, name, description)
{
CHobjects *node;
CHobjects newNode;

    node=CHobjects;
    while(node!=NULL)
    {
        if(node->instance==instance) 
            return 
        node=node->next; 
    }
    if(strlen((char *)objectName)>objectNameMax || strlen((char *)description)>descriptionMax)
        goto cc8; //fail name or description is too long
// if((node=(CHobject *)malloc(sizeof(CHobject)))==NULL) //get a block of space for this object's info
// goto cc8; //fail if we can't get space for it
    test.next=CHobjects; //link on to list
    CHobjects=&test;
    CHcount++;
}
```

This code simply adds the elements to the list, the whole code would afterwards set some variables to default values.

Comment: Please show your actual code. Where is `objectName` defined? Where is `CHobject` defined?

Comment: Please post the real code. Also, use good formatting `strlen((char *)objectName)>objectNameMax` and `strlen((char *)objectName->objectNameMax` look identical and are confusing.

Comment: it will compile but with assuming integer type

Comment: The real types are large bacnet structs that I can not pass around.

Comment: So you will get pseudo answers

Comment: What does `node = CHobjects` mean? `CHobjects` is a type. You're saying there's an infinite loop. Are you saying then that it's in the `while` statement shown? It's the only loop you're showing. That would mean your linked list wasn't properly constructed with a NULL for the last element's `next` attribute.

Comment: if the space for the variable` newNode` is allocated on the stack, the space allocated for it at run time goes away after the function`newNode` returns.

Comment: I put in the object types which are 'CHobjects', after the second item is added to the list, the list becomes improperly terminated. I can not see why and this is my question. The code posted is the entire adding of elements to the list, the rest of the code is setting variables

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I apologize, that came right from the code provider, I am trying to edit some propitiatory code to fix our needs

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. CHobjects seems to be a struct type, but later you use this symbol in assignments like pointers to this struct. Obviously you edited the code in an improper way to hide proprietary derails. However, this obfuscation makes it almost impossible to help you.

Comment: @user6060561 CHobjects is a stuct and I want a linked list of them. I can not use malloc to create new CHobject instances. To get around this I am attempting to create a local instance of CHobject and add that to my list

Comment: OK, I think I got your intention. Note that you cannot add a locally created structure to a list that will be used outside this function, because the instance is allocated on the stack, and will be destroyed as soon as the function returns. Are we talking about C or C++? In plain C, you're quite out if luck if you can't use the heap.

Comment: @user6060561 while that makes sense, I call this function 4 times. The first two times it works as expected and I have two items in my list. It is not until the 3rd function call that I hit the infinite loop

Comment: Yeah, you get the same structure instance on each call, because the stack space is recycled, so you link the structure to itself. After two calls, you've got a circular list. You need some permanent storage, local variables are volatile. If you're in a plain C environment and can't use the heap, you should create a global array of structures large enough to satisfy all of your allocations. Instead of calling malloc, use the next slot in your array. Basically, you roll your own heap.

Comment: @MichaelMiner the problem is you are invoking ***Undefined Behavior*** by attempting to access a variable (a struct in your case) that has *gone out of scope* and is **no longer guaranteed** to exist. By attempting to access it you invoke *Undefined Behavior*. Can the memory for the first 2 still exist on the stack? -- sure. They may not have been overwritten yet, how and when values that have gone out of scope are overwritten is not defined by C. Your attempted use of a statically allocated local instance of the struct is the problem. Why is `malloc` failing is the real question?

Answer (score 1):

After our extensive discussion in the comments, I think it's obvious that you problem is the use of local struct instances in a global list. The structs you create on the stack become invalid on exiting the newNode() function, and the same stack space is recycled on the next call. So you link the same instance to itself, and after two calls, you've got a circular list, and enter an infinite loop.

Since you're obviously on plain C without a heap, your only chance is to roll your own struct allocator in global memory, preallocated at compile time. Declare a global array of CHobjects large enough to satisfy all of you allocations (i.e. the maximum length of the list). In your case, this seems to be 4. Here's a raw outline:

```
#define CHOBJECTS_MAX 4

static CHobjects gaCHobjects [CHOBJECTS_MAX];
static int giNextSlot = 0;

public: static CHobjects* Allocator ()
    {
    return gaCHObjects + giNextSlot++;
    }
```

The function Allocator() returns a struct pointer from your global array and increments the giNextSlot index, so you get a new instance on each invocation. Use this pointer inside newNode() instead of a local CHobjects instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think that it's possible to give you a useful answer anyway.

The only way I can think that you can implement this is using an array as the storage for the linked list, and as a plus you will have both an array and a linked list at the same time

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct list {
    int value;
    struct list *next;
};

static void
print_list(const struct list *item)
{
    while (item->next != NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", item->value);
        item = item->next;
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct list items[15];
    size_t count;

    count = sizeof items / sizeof *items - 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index) {
        items[index].next = &items[index + 1];
        items[index].value = index + 1;
    }
    items[count].next = NULL;

    print_list(items);
}
```

As you see, you need access to the given array element to use as storage location, and the array must be valid through the life time of the linked list.

Comment: I have tried to make my question more clear. The code posted above is complete as any other code simply sets default values. I can not change the code structure but I need to replace the use of malloc.